# How could I refresh function in 'onsubmit' form everytime new input is put?

Tags: php, html, forms, repeat, onsubmit

I am writing a program to ask user to input their 'first, last name, email, phone number'

```
<script>
function validate1(){
alert ("validate1 called");
var elemFname = document.getElementById("idFname");
var elemFnameValue=elemFname.value;
var elemFnameErr = document.getElementById("idFnameErr");

var elemLname = document.getElementById("idLname");
var elemLnameValue=elemLname.value;
var elemLnameErr = document.getElementById("idLnameErr");

var elemidEmail = document.getElementById("idEmail");
var elemidEmailValue=elemidEmail.value;
var elemidEmailErr = document.getElementById("idEmailErr");

var elemidPhone = document.getElementById("idPhone");
var elemidPhoneValue=elemidPhone.value;
var elemidPhoneErr = document.getElementById("idPhoneErr");


if (elemFnameValue==null || elemFnameValue=="" || elemLnameValue==null ||    elemLnameValue=="" || elemidEmailValue==null || elemidEmailValue=="" ||      elemidPhoneValue==null || elemidPhoneValue==""){


if (elemFnameValue==null || elemFnameValue=="" ){
    elemFnameErr.innerHTML="Require Field";
}
if (elemLnameValue==null || elemLnameValue==""){
        elemLnameErr.innerHTML="Require Field";
}
if (elemidEmailValue==null || elemidEmailValue==""){
        elemidEmailErr.innerHTML="Require Field";
}
if (elemidPhoneValue==null || elemidPhoneValue==""){
        elemidPhoneErr.innerHTML="Require Field";
}

    return false;
}       

else{
    return true;
}
```

}

and,

```
<body>
<form onsubmit="return validate1()" action = "contactinfo.php">
First Name<span style="color:red">*</span><input type="text" name = "Fname" size = "10"  id="idFname" />
    <span id="idFnameErr" style="color:red"></span><br>
Last Name<span style="color:red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name = "Lname" size = "10" id="idLname" />
    <span id="idLnameErr" style="color:red"></span><br>
Email<span style="color:red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name = "InpEmail" size = "10" id="idEmail" />
    <span id="idEmailErr" style="color:red"></span><br>
Phone<span style="color:red">*</span>
    <input type="text" name = "InpPhone" size="10" id="idPhone" />
    <span id="idPhoneErr" ></span><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /><br>


</form>
</body>
```

I am trying to figure out how I could get it to refresh the value of inputs 'InpEmail, InpPhone, Fname,Lname for function validate() and its variables (such as elemFname, elemLname).

Right now, for example, if I put nothing on 'text input' for First Name, which will return me 'false' giving output "Require Field" next to the corresponding textbox by validate();, next time I fill in that textbox for First Name and leaving other textboxes (for phone,email, lastname) empty, the output "Required Field" will still remain next to the textbox for 'First Name' in addition to others that are now empty.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Add your validate code to the onchange for each individual input.

```
<input type="text" name = "Lname" size = "10" id="idLname" onchange="validate1();"/>
```

If you go this route, you probably want to have a validate for each input

Comment: This still won't remove the "required field" message from fields which have since been populated

Comment: In the validate you would set the message, it allows you to have more control over what the message says.  Typically I would set it to blank first and then if it is invalid change it again to an error message

Answer (score 0):

You could add an alternate condition on your if statements:

```
if (elemFnameValue==null || elemFnameValue=="" ){
    elemFnameErr.innerHTML="Require Field";
}else{
   elemFnameErr.innerHTML="";
}
```

But I would spend a bit of time to learn angular.js or jquery.validate()

It will save you a lot of time in the long run